# Is it possible to have something like authoryear-icomp without ibid?

Tags: biblatex

Is it possible to have two adjacent citations with same author and same year where the second citation omits both author and year but prints only a given page?

It should look like

> Opitz et al. (2013) as the 1st mention and then (p. 254) as the 2nd mention

rather than

> Opitz et al. (2013) as the 1st mention and then (Opitz et al. 2013, p. 254) as the 2nd mention

`authoryear-icomp` almost allows me to get what I desire:

> Opitz et al. (2013) as the 1st mention and then (ibid., p. 254) as the 2nd mention.

However, the APA style does not use ibid. Does somebody have a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

In `biblatex-icomp` the bibmacro `cite:ibid` is responsible for printing the 'ibid.' citation. We can easily redefine it so it prints nothing if there is a page reference. (I decided to output a warning and 'ibid.' in case there is no page reference to avoid an empty citation.)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {\PackageWarning{biblatex}{%
       'ibid' citation without postnote,\MessageBreak
       printing 'ibid' to avoid an empty citation\MessageBreak}%
     \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson} ipsum \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}

Lorem \autocite{nussbaum} ipsum \autocite{nussbaum}

Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson} ipsum \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) ipsum (p. 380)//Lorem (Nussbaum 1978) ipsum (ibid.)//Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 380) ipsum (p. 380)]

In case you are shopping for styles, I think Chicago style behaves similarly in author-year "mode", so `biblatex-chicago` or `windycity` might be of interest. (Of course Chicago style is quite complex, so these styles have to do a lot of work to get things right. If you are looking for a lightweight solution that is easily customisable, you are definitely better of with the standard style `biblatex-icomp`.)